# HID Omnikey 5427 CK not working in KBW mode

Tags: windows, rfid, hid, omnikey, keyboard-wedge

I use a HID Omnikey 5427 CK reader and when I switch to KBW mode, Windows stops seeing it, it appears in Device Manager as a HID input device with the error "Code 10 The device cannot be started", the CDC EEM driver is also not seen by the reader, I can not enter the web interface and somehow configure it. In the CCID protocol, the reader is visible to the system, but the EEM driver still does not work. Try connect reader for MacOS and it works in all modes, but there are no EEM drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

> With the keyboard wedge functionality, users of OMNIKEY 5x27 CK
> readers can retrieve data from a card that is presented to the reader
> and directly input the card data into an application using keystroke
> emulation. This eliminates the need for customers to manually enter
> the card data into an application.
>
> This guide explains how to setup the reader to use different card
> types in the Keyboard Wedge mode using the web browser interface.
>
> To use the reader browser interface, the EEM-USB driver must be
> installed. For installation instructions, see the OMNIKEY 5x27CK Quick
> Start Guide (5127-901).
>
> Note: HID provides various Service Packs for the OMNIKEY 5x27CK. Some
> functions have been introduced with later Service Packs only. These
> exceptions are noted in this user guide. For downloading the latest
> Service Pack for your OMNIKEY 5x27CK reader, access the Developer
> Center: [www.hidglobal.com/developer-center/OMNIKEY-5x27ck](http://www.hidglobal.com/developer-center/OMNIKEY-5x27ck).
>
> Service Packs are available in the Downloads section, which requires a
> user account. Check the firmware version of the OMNIKEY 5x27CK Reader
> from the General Overview tab in the built-in web interface. See 2.1
> Reader web-based management tool interface.

https://www.hidglobal.com/sites/default/files/resource_files/5127-902-e.4-omnikey-5x27ck-keyboard-wedge-user-guide_0.pdf

Comment: I tryed but reader doesn't seen by Windows

Comment: this guide should have all instrustions for your reader. have you tried to connect your reader to different PC?

Comment: From manual:
Note: Due to how the Windows OS manages instances of devices, HID recommends that a single 5427CK device is used to build configurations. The configurations should be applied via configuration cards on a different host OS device. If this cannot be done, care must be taken to manage the device instances in Windows to prevent computer issues.

Comment: I haven't many pcs wisth Windows, but tried connect to Oracle VM virtualbox and it's working, if anyone needs a solution of this problem, i will answer here

Comment: This HID User Guide omits a critical step after installation of the EEM-USB driver.  That driver creates a network interface.  The interface gets a random autoconfigured IP address.  To reach the Omnikey web server, an appropriate address must be assigned to the interface, e.g. 192.168.63.1.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by connecting the reader to the system on a Oracle VM virtualbox. I will try connect to other computers, I think it will work.